# PHP arrays difference without making use of array_diff

Tags: php

```php
  $tag=[25, 26];
  $tagarray[]=[25,29,30,44,26];
```

I need a result of [29,30,44]. Here my main array is `tagarray`. and tested it with `tag` array. I need unmatched values from `tagarray` without any array function like `array_diff()`.I want to compare both arrays and only provide the elements from `tagarray` which are not present in `tag` array.

```
    $missings = [];
        $matches = false;
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($tagarray); $i++ ) {
            $matches = false;
            for ($e = 0; $e < count($tag); $e++ ) {
                if ( $tagarray[$i] == $tag[$e] ) $matches = true;
            }
            if(!$matches) array_push($missings,$tagarray[$i]);
        }
        dd($missings);
```

Comment: $missings = [];
    $matches = false;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($tagarray); $i++ ) {
        $matches = false;
        for ($e = 0; $e < count($tag); $e++ ) {
            if ( $tagarray[$i] == $tag[$e] ) $matches = true;
        }
        if(!$matches) array_push($missings,$tagarray[$i]);
    }
    dd($missings);

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `array_diff()` then you can use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$res = [];
foreach($tagarray[0] as $val){
    if (!in_array($val,$tag)) $res[] = $val;
}
print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 29
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 44
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Eaist)**

If `$tagarray` has more then 1 element:

```
$tag=[25, 26];
$tagarray[]=[25,29,30,44,26];
$tagarray[]=[25,22,11,44,26];

$res = [];
foreach($tagarray as $ind=>$tagar){
    foreach($tagar as $val){
        if (!in_array($val,$tag)) $res[$ind][] = $val;
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 29
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 44
        )

)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nf84W)**

**Third** Without any inbuilt PHP array function:

```
$tagar_l = count($tagarray);
$tag_l = count($tag);
$tagar_0_l = count($tagarray[0]);

$res = [];
for($i = 0; $i<$tagar_l; $i++){

    $res[] = $tagarray[$i];

    for($j = 0; $j<$tagar_0_l; $j++){ 
        for($k = 0; $k<$tag_l; $k++){ 
            if ($tag[$k] === $tagarray[$i][$j]) unset($res[$i][$j]);
        }   
    }  
    sort($res[$i]);
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Kbagj)**

Via `foreach` loop:

```
$res = [];

foreach($tagarray as $ind=>$arr){
    $res[] = $arr;
    foreach($arr as $ind_a=>$val){
        foreach($tag as $comp){
            if ($comp === $val) unset($res[$ind][$ind_a]);
        }
    }
    sort($res[$ind]);
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2mlr2)**

Comment: It's so hard to set `[0]` index. updated. If you need dynamic `tagarray` then

Comment: still i get this 25,26

Comment: @SindhuDiya, you can't get this result. Check demos

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 29 [2] => 30 [3] => 44 [4] => 26 ) )

Comment: @SindhuDiya, check first demo. Come on.

Comment: s i saw that, its correct, bt when i print that res[] it gets above array

Comment: tagarray is like this array:1 [
  0 => array:5 [
    0 => "25"
    1 => "29"
    2 => "30"
    3 => "44"
    4 => "26"
  ]
]

Comment: @SindhuDiya, the third demo should works also. Check it

Comment: @SindhuDiya, you're welcome, you can try it via `while` loop or `foreach` as well. updated for `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

You need `nested for loops` to loop over each element of your array to filter, and for each of these elements, loop on the array containing the filters.
Since you do not want to use any of the `array` function, you need to use a `boolean` to check whether or not the index was to be filtered or not and make use of a 3rd array to store the filtered array.

Take a look:

```
$tag = [25, 26];
$tagarray = [25,29,30,44,26];
$filteredArray = [];


for($i = 0; $i < count($tagarray); ++$i){
  $toRemove = false;
  for($j = 0; $j < count($tag); ++$j){
    if($tagarray[$i] == $tag[$j]){
        $toRemove = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if(!$toRemove){
     $filteredArray[] = $tagarray[$i]; 
  }
}

var_dump($filteredArray);
```

Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(29)
  [1]=>
  int(30)
  [2]=>
  int(44)
}
```

I would personally not choose this solution and go with Aksen's one, but since you do not want to use any `array` functions I assume that this is a school assignment and that you have no other choices ;)